# poner 2 videos de YouTube en un mismo activity

Tags: video, youtube

Tengo este Activity (videomedia)
y pude hacer que me reproduzca uno de los videos pero no se como importar el segundo video de Youtube, tengo a librería importada sin problemas y con un solo video si funciona la app hasta ahora.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_videomedia);

    youTubePlayerView=(YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(claveYoutube,this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean fueRestaurado) {
    if (!fueRestaurado){
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo("N9SPr-xvLGc"); //https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N9SPr-xvLGc



    }

}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {


    if (youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()){
        youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(this, 1).show();
    }else {
        String error = "Error al inicializar Youtube"+youTubeInitializationResult.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestcCode, int resultcode, Intent data){
    if (resultcode==1){
        getYoutubePlayerProvider().initialize(claveYoutube,this);

    }
}

protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYoutubePlayerProvider(){
    return youTubePlayerView;

}

@Override
public void onPlaying() {

}

@Override
public void onPaused() {

}

@Override
public void onStopped() {

}

@Override
public void onBuffering(boolean b) {

}

@Override
public void onSeekTo(int i) {

}
```

}

//Este es mi xml:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".videomedia">
```

primer video

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="141dp"/>
```

segundo video

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.
    android:id="@+id/youtube_view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="141dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="266dp"/>
```

El videomedio.java solo pude programarlo para que reproduzca el primer video, pero el segundo video como podria hacerlo desde que parte del código deberia repetir el método. Cuando trato de repetirlo me cierra la aplicación.

Hasta ahora solo consigo esto:
[image: solo reproduce el primer video]

Comment: Lo siento Jhon Andy, esto no es posible usando YouTubePlayerView.

Comment: una posible solucion es usar webview aunque queda un poco extraña la vista

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al usar la [YoutubePlayer API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer?hl=es) hay ciertas restricciones que debes tomar en cuenta:

- La vista debe ser como minimo de 200px X 200px.
- No se debe agregar una vista arriba del player.
- **Únicamente se permite un player para reproducción dentro de la misma `Activity` , incluso si cada player se encuentra en un `Fragment` diferente dentro de la `Activity` no se permite la reproducción.**